# Adding background Image to a button using PhotoChooserTask

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to insert image in a button through photochoosertask

but on casting btnSelectImage.Content as Image it gives null

can you please help me out

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            Image contentImage = btnSelectImage.Content as Image;
            if (contentImage != null)
            {
                contentImage.Source = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(e.OriginalFileName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            contentImage.Source = bitmap;
        }
    }
```

Try this.

I am not sure what you xaml looks like. You'll have to use it this way

```
<Button>
     <Image x:Name="contentImage" />
</Button>
```

Comment: Problem is - contentImage is coming null

Comment: <Button Content="Select Image" Height="200" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="btnSelectImage" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Click="btnSelectImage_Click" Background="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Opacity="1" />